# Iterate all over tcp stream in pcap file with Scapy

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, pcap

There is `pcap` file that contains some tcp stream , In wireshark there is filter `tcp.stream eq 0`  `tcp.stream eq 1` ... to see only packet from specific tcp stream.

Is there any way with SCAPY to iterate all packets by tcp stream? I want to print all packet data by TCP stream like :

stream 0 : <packet 1>  <packet 2>

stream 1 : <packet 3>  <packet 4>

Answer (score 0):

May be sniff function with parameter offline and session could satisfy your requirement.

```
from scapy.all import sniff, TCPSession
s = sniff(offline="h:/datasets/s1.pcap", session=TCPSession)
```